# selecting item from a database in java

Tags: java

i want to insert data in a database from jtextfield but with some condition

so i tried this code

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String m = "IMCDietitian";
        String unicode= "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+m+""+unicode+"","root","");
        System.out.println("connected");
        String dept = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (jTextField6.getText() != null)
        {
            String pname = jTextField6.getText();
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM '"+dept+"' WHERE pname = '"+pname+"' ");
            while (rs.next())
            {
                if (!rs.getString(8).equals("-") && rs.getString(1).equals(pname) )
                {
                    if (jCheckBox1.isSelected() == true)
                    {
                        st.executeQuery("INSERT INTO '"+dept+"' VALUES ('"+jTextField6.getText()+"', '"+jTextField5.getText()+"', '"+jTextField4.getText()+"', 'يوجد', '"+jTextField3.getText()+"', '"+jTextField2.getText()+"', '"+jTextField1.getText()+"', '-'");
                    }
                    if (jCheckBox1.isSelected() == false)
                    {
                        st.executeQuery("INSERT INTO '"+dept+"' VALUES ('"+jTextField6.getText()+"', '"+jTextField5.getText()+"', '"+jTextField4.getText()+"', 'لا يوجد', '-', '"+jTextField2.getText()+"', '"+jTextField1.getText()+"', '-'");
                    }
                }
                if (!rs.getString(1).equals(pname))
                {
                    if (jCheckBox1.isSelected() == true)
                    {
                        st.executeQuery("INSERT INTO '"+dept+"' VALUES ('"+jTextField6.getText()+"', '"+jTextField5.getText()+"', '"+jTextField4.getText()+"', 'يوجد', '"+jTextField3.getText()+"', '"+jTextField2.getText()+"', '"+jTextField1.getText()+"', '-'");
                    }
                    if (jCheckBox1.isSelected() == false)
                    {
                        st.executeQuery("INSERT INTO '"+dept+"' VALUES ('"+jTextField6.getText()+"', '"+jTextField5.getText()+"', '"+jTextField4.getText()+"', 'لا يوجد', '-', '"+jTextField2.getText()+"', '"+jTextField1.getText()+"', '-'");
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

but this error is accour

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''gc' WHERE pname = 'Ù…Ø­Ù…Ø¯'' at line 1
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1383)
        at dietition.EDietListJFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(EDietListJFrame.java:2351)
        at dietition.EDietListJFrame.access$900(EDietListJFrame.java:29)
        at dietition.EDietListJFrame$10.actionPerformed(EDietListJFrame.java:963)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6263)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

++++Whats that? wkey 0x42 (66)

any one can help?

Comment: It seems like an encoding problem, I see you are using some arabic chars

Comment: never use user input directly for a sql query, this is a potential security risk http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp
Use Prepared Statements instead http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: The error message is quite explicit: ``You have an error in your SQL``. You should add some debug output to your code, so you can see how your queries look like. I suppose, you ran into encoding problems, since you use arabic characters.

Comment: could you try removing the ' sourrounding the dept in your query and either replace them with ` or just leave them?

Comment: @wastl i tried to remove the comma and it doesn't insert the data but it remove the error but this sentence is appear "  ++++Whats that? wkey 0x42 (66)"

Comment: Are u have any solution for that?

Comment: could you maybe post a sample of what value dept might have? Furhtermore, where does the sentence appear?

Comment: The value dept come from the string that have been selected from the comboBox and also it is one of the tables name in the imcdietition database. The table names and also the comboBox is "gc, 1c, 1b, 2c, 2b, 3c, 4c, icu". And this sentence appear in the output window the same place of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `N` before the arabic text:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column=N'arabic text'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the structure of your code is totally not what one would want to see in production grade code. Accessing a database directly from UI components will most likely become a problem in some point of time.

Nevertheless the Exception you get is quite clear. The JDBC driver is not able to interpret your SQL statement. The reason for that is that it is not able to understand the arabic characters in your insert statements.

You should follow the hint of user wastl in the comments and use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Which not only help you avoid potential security risk in form of [SQL injections](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), but will also help with non ASCII character encoding in your statements.

Once you have understood and mastered prepared statements you perhaps want to move to a more elaborate data model whit object to relational mapping as available in [javax.persistence](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/package-summary.html) and its famous [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems syntax error due to single comma ['], you may need to skip it by using backslash [] before single comma ['] and for that purpose you can use below mentioned syntax :

update user set firstName = 'Ù…Ø­Ù…Ø¯\'' where userid = 'test';